# Method to concatenate 2 Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, refactoring, concatenation

I have a method in Java that concatenates 2 Strings.  It currently works correctly, but I think it can be written better.

```
public static String concat(String str1, String str2) {
  String rVal = null;
  if (str1 != null || str2 != null) {
    rVal = "";
    if (str1 != null) {
      rVal += str1;
    }
    if (str2 != null) {
      rVal += str2;
    }      
  }    
  return rVal;
}
```

Here are some of the requirements:

1. If both str1 and str2 are null, the method returns null
2. If either str1 or str2 is null, it will just return the not null String
3. If str1 and str2 are not null, it will concatenate them
4. It never adds "null" to the result

Can anyone do this with less code?

Comment: If I call str1.concat(str2), it will throw a NullPointerException when str1 is null.

Comment: Couldn't you just use the StringBuilder?

Comment: @Ant I am not sure that handles the null cases very well.

Comment: This question really has 7 votes? Really? Just to be able to re-write the same thing with a ternary operator?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure:

```
public static String concat(String str1, String str2) {
  return str1 == null ? str2
      : str2 == null ? str1
      : str1 + str2;
}
```

Note that this takes care of the "both null" case in the first condition: if `str1` is null, then you either want to return null (if `str2` is null) or `str2` (if `str2` is not null) - both of which are handled by just returning `str2`.

Comment: Nested conditional operators? Seriously?

Comment: Some can read it, some cannot. It's indeed more confusing for starters. I would rather have put them in a single line with parentheses. Something like `return (str1 == null) ? str2 : ((str2 == null) ? str1 : (str1 + str2));`

Comment: @Michael: Absolutely - I find it a very useful pattern when you want to test multiple conditions with a preference.

Comment: @BalusC: I find the parentheses add confusion whereas the line breaks show the logical structure more clearly. It's a personal preference thing though.

Comment: *urks* Please add the version without conditional operator for completeness and beauty. Sometimes more code is less confusion!

Comment: @Jon Skeet: true, it's personal. But I've experienced that starters understand it better when you use parentheses to separate conditions and expressions. After a year or five, they will start write and understand it without parentheses ;) As the OP is already asking this relatively simple question, I bet that he falls in the category "starter".

Comment: @Jon: Useful yes, but utterly baffling when you're not used to it, and IMO not useful enough to inflict it on unsuspecting newbies.

Comment: Thanks Jon and Michael.  I prefer Jon's method because I don't mind conditionals.  I also prefer one return statement per method.

Answer (score 15):

Using only plain `if` clauses:

```
public static String concat(String str1, String str2) {
    if(str1==null) return str2;
    if(str2==null) return str1;
    return str1 + str2;
}
```

Or, if you have a deep and passionate love for parentheses:

```
public static String concat(String str1, String str2) {
    if(str1==null)
    { 
        return str2;
    }
    if(str2==null) 
    {
        return str1;
    }
    return str1 + str2;
}
```

Comment: You don't like nested conditionals - I don't like `if` statements without braces :)

Comment: @Jon had those at first, but compactness IMO is better in such a simple case.

Answer (score 4):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

StringUtils.join([str1, str2]);
```

Joins the elements of the provided array into a single String containing the provided list of elements.

No separator is added to the joined String. Null objects or empty strings within the array are represented by empty strings.

```
 StringUtils.join(null)            = null
 StringUtils.join([])              = ""
 StringUtils.join([null])          = ""
 StringUtils.join(["a", "b", "c"]) = "abc"
 StringUtils.join([null, "", "a"]) = "a"
```

Comment: @Nishu This is close, but a simple null check is needed in case both str1 and str2 are both null.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone seems to have missed condition 1 where if both strings are null it returns null.  The simplest version to read (IMO) then becomes:

```
public static String concat(String str1, String str2) {  
    if(str1==null && str2==null) return null;  
    if(str1==null) return str2;  
    if(str2==null) return str1;  
    return str1 + str2;  
}
```

Comment: Both Jon and Michael's solutions would return null on the first condition (returning the other String, which is null) if both strings are null. Yours just adds an extra unnecessary test condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ConcatTest extends TestCase {

    // 1. If both str1 and str2 are null, the method returns null
    public void testBothNull() throws Exception {
        assertNull(concat(null, null));
    }

    // 2. If either str1 or str2 is null, it will just return the not null
    // String
    public void testOneNull() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("a", concat(null, "a"));
        assertEquals("b", concat("b", null));
    }

    // 3. If str1 and str2 are not null, it will concatenate them
    public void testNonNull() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("ab", concat("a", "b"));
    }

    // 4. It never adds "null" to the result (not really testable)

    public static String concat(String a, String b) {
        if (a == null && b == null)
            return null;
        return denulled(a) + denulled(b);
    }

    private static String denulled(String s) {
        return s == null ? "" : s;
    }

}
```